# Can we use the R purrr accumulate function to summarise a dataset?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to summarise a dataset by using the `purrr::accumulate` function to create the summary by incrementally added a new variable.

So I am trying to get the total_years, total_cnt and percent incrementally by adding one variable at a time.  Below is what I have tried, but I am getting an unused argument error and I am not sure why.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


data <- tribble(~age_grp, ~gender, ~eligible, ~years, ~cnt,
       '50-60', "F", 0, 4, 1,
       '75-80', "M", 0, 7, 1,
       '80+', "M", 1, 0, 1,
       '60-70', "F", 1, 2, 1,
       '60-70', "F", 1, 3, 1,
       '50-60', "M", 0, 1, 1
       )

#  `eligible` is binary

vars <- c('gender', 'eligible', 'years') %>% 
        accumulate(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep = "+"),
                   .init = 'age_grp') %>% 
        set_names(1:length(.))
enframe(vars, name = 'iteration', value = 'values')

fnct <- function(x) {
        data %>% 
        summarise(
                total_years     = sum(years),
                total_cnt       = sum(cnt)) %>% 
        mutate(
                percent         = total_years/(total_cnt))
}

vars %>% 
        map(fnct, data = data)
```

Comment: The error is logical since you pass `data = data` in function `fnct` but there is no argument in `fnct` that accepts it. If you run `vars %>% map(fnct)` the error goes away. Although, I am not sure what is your expected output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly your approach, but basically you can do this through grouping.

```r
# error in your function, i think you meant to use x instead of data
fnct <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    summarise(
      total_years     = sum(years),
      total_cnt       = sum(cnt)) %>% 
    mutate(
      percent         = total_years/(total_cnt))
}

# these seem to be your grouping variables
grp_vars <- c('age_grp', 'gender', 'eligible')

# this map will first group on variable 1, then on 1 and 2, and so on
map(seq_along(grp_vars), ~ fnct(group_by_at(data, grp_vars[seq.int(.x)])))
```

This will return a list of tibbles. You can easily use `bind_rows()` or grab whatever column you want.

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  age_grp total_years total_cnt percent
  <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 50-60             5         2     2.5
2 60-70             5         2     2.5
3 75-80             7         1     7  
4 80+               0         1     0  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   age_grp [4]
  age_grp gender total_years total_cnt percent
  <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 50-60   F                4         1     4  
2 50-60   M                1         1     1  
3 60-70   F                5         2     2.5
4 75-80   M                7         1     7  
5 80+     M                0         1     0  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   age_grp, gender [5]
  age_grp gender eligible total_years total_cnt percent
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 50-60   F             0           4         1     4  
2 50-60   M             0           1         1     1  
3 60-70   F             1           5         2     2.5
4 75-80   M             0           7         1     7  
5 80+     M             1           0         1     0
```

Comment: I think this might work.  Do you know what I would need to change to only sum the values when the binary value (eligible) is a 1?

Comment: Perhaps add `filter(eligible == 1)` at the beginning of the pipe in the function? To make this always work, you can add into that function a line that if the column doesn't exist, add it with a value of 1? Something like that to play around with.